# jqGrid and Icon (expand,collapse) for grouping or tree mode 

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jqgrid

Can someone help me understand with jqGrid an example, to send me an email in tandem ASP.NET (C#), so that there was work to a tree adjacency transition ,paging and other grid simply grouping on the field and paging. I can show my project. Source from [link here](http://www.vininfo.com.ua/tmp/my.zip)
I can not get icons to display the grid nodes in the tree and also fails to display icons for the node grouping in the field.
Help please.

not displayed icons for node grouping [image link here](http://www.vininfo.com.ua/tmp/1.png)

not displayed icons for tree nodes (in top image link change 1.png to 2.png)

```
  function successFunctionST(jsondata) {
   var thegrid = jQuery("#gridST")[0];
   thegrid.addJSONData(JSON.parse(jsondata.d));
   }

 function getST() {
    $.ajax({
    url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/FetchData.asmx/bindST") %>',
    data: "{}",  
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: successFunctionST
    });
  }

function ST() {
$("#tabs-2").css('display', '');
$("#ST").css('display', '');
$("#t2").css('display', '');
$('#tabs').css('display', '');
$("#tabs").tabs({ selected: 1 });

jQuery("#gridST").jqGrid({
    height: "100%",
    width: 900,
    datatype: getST,
    colNames: ['Id', 'F', 'I', 'O', 'JobPosition', 'Phone1', 'Phone2', 'Email',       'User', 'SCentr'],
    colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'id', width: 10, hidden: true, key: true },
                { name: 'F', index: 'F', width: 80 },
                { name: 'I', index: 'I', width: 80 },
                { name: 'O', index: 'O', width: 20 },
                { name: 'JobPosition', index: 'JobPosition', width: 90 },
                { name: 'Phone1', index: 'Phone1', width: 90 },
                { name: 'Phone2', index: 'Phone2', width: 20 },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 20 },
                { name: 'User', index: 'User', width: 20 },
                { name: 'SCentr', index: 'SCentr', width: 30 }
              ],
    rowNum: 15,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
    sortname: 'SCentr',
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: ['SCentr'],
        groupColumnShow: [true],
        groupCollapse: false,
        groupOrder: ['asc']
    },
    pager: jQuery('#pjmapST'),
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true
  });
   }
```

json

```
"{total: '1', page: '1', records: '1', rows : [ {id:'1', cell:[ '1', 'Петров',  
     'Петр', 'Иванович', 'Директор', '1', '1', '1@3.ru', 'Admin', 'Сервисные центры
      1'] },{id:'2', cell:[ '2', 'Іванов', 'Іван', 'Петрович', 'Бухгалтер', '1', '1',  
     '1@3.ru', 'User', '' ] } ] }"
```

and json

```
"{total: '1', page: '1', records: '1', rows : [ {id:'1', cell:[ '1', 'Сервисные центры 1', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Винница', 'Красных партизан 1', '123-321', 'mail@mail.ru', 'www.service1', '0', 'null', 'false', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'2', cell:[ '4', 'Сервисный центр 1_2', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service2', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'3', cell:[ '5', 'Сервисный центр 1_3', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service3', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'4', cell:[ '6', 'Сервисный центр 1_4', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service4', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'5', cell:[ '8', 'Сервисный центр 1_6', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service6', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'6', cell:[ '9', 'Сервисный центр 1_7', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service7', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'7', cell:[ '10', 'Сервисный центр 1_8', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service8', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'8', cell:[ '11', 'Сервисный центр 1_9', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service9', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'9', cell:[ '12', 'Сервисный центр 1_10', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service10', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'10', cell:[ '13', 'Сервисный центр 1_11', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service11', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'11', cell:[ '14', 'Сервисный центр 1_12', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service12', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'12', cell:[ '15', 'Сервисный центр 1_13', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service13', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'13', cell:[ '16', 'Сервисный центр 1_14', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service14', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'14', cell:[ '17', 'Сервисный центр 1_15', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service15', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'15', cell:[ '18', 'Сервисный центр 1_16', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service16', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'16', cell:[ '19', 'Сервисный центр 1_17', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service17', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'17', cell:[ '20', 'Сервисный центр 1_18', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service18', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'18', cell:[ '21', 'Сервисный центр 1_19', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service19', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'19', cell:[ '22', 'Сервисный центр 1_20', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service20', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'20', cell:[ '23', 'Сервисный центр 1_21', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service21', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'21', cell:[ '24', 'Сервисный центр 1_22', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service22', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'22', cell:[ '25', 'Сервисный центр 1_23', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service23', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'23', cell:[ '26', 'Сервисный центр 1_24', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service24', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'24', cell:[ '27', 'Сервисный центр 1_25', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service25', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'true' ] },{id:'25', cell:[ '28', 'Сервисный центр 2', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Киев', 'Артема', '123-321', 'fert@ukr.net', 'www.service26', '0', 'null', 'false', 'false', 'true' ] } ] }"
```

Comment: I can't download [my.zip](http://www.vininfo.com.ua/tmp/my.zip). Could you verify the link? You should modify your server response in any way because it's not a JSON. Strings must be encoded as "string" and not as 'string'. See http://www.json.org/. You can verify JSON in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Oleg try download my.zip again please.

Comment: I can now download the project, but to tell the trust I am disappointed. I thought that you prepared a demo which demonstrate *the problem*. Instead of that I see the code with too much unneeded things. To test the code I have to create DB from many scripts and so on. All text files are saved not in Unicode, so I can't directly read comments in Russian. I would like to help you, but I can't spend my time in preparation of the project which you send - I have to do my main job also. Could you reduce the project and prepared it to be used directly?

Comment: Why you don't use `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` attributes of ASMX web service? In the case serialization to JSON do .NET and you should return just objects. I suppose that the object will be twice converted in JSON - at the first time with `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` and at the second time the string which you returned will be serialized to JSON at the next time and all `"` will be escaped to `\"`. If you really need to use `Newtonsoft.Json` you should use WFC instead of ASMX. It's just my general remarks. Your main problem can be solved in any way.

Comment: I am student, will create a demo project which will display my problem with grids. If you can send me an email in my profile. In the near future will place a link. Thank you Oleg.

Comment: You can contact me using the following address oleg.kiriljuk@ok-soft-gmbh.com